# JS - passing a connection(object) from one function to another

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to JS and I have a simple question. I am writing a node_redis code to connect to the db.
I have created a db module in which there is an init function to start the connection.
the module also has another function which queries the db. for the query, i will need the connection (dbConnection) object from the first function and then use it in the 2nd function. how do i do this? I can get it done by using global variables but most places tell me its a bad idea.

Sorry if the question is stupid, I am learning how to code. results in google tell me that it can be done by passing it as an object property. But i don't know if it is the proper way to do things in my context, or even how to do it.

```
var redis = require('redis'); 

module.exports = redisDb = {
// Initialize the module. Invokes callback when ready (or on error)
init: function(config, callback) {

    // Open the database connection
    var dbConnection = redis.createClient(config.db.port, config.db.host, {no_ready_check: true}); 

    dbConnection.auth(config.db.authKey, function() {
        console.log("Connected!");
        console.log(dbConnection.keys('*'));
    });

    dbConnection.on('connect'     , log('connect'));
    dbConnection.on('ready'       , log('ready'));
    dbConnection.on('reconnecting', log('reconnecting'));
    dbConnection.on('error'       , log('error'));
    dbConnection.on('idle'         , log('idle...'));
    dbConnection.on('end'         , log('end'));

    function log(type) {
        return function() {
            console.log(type, arguments);
        }
    }
    callback("callback - Connected");
},

getValue: function(key, callback) {
    dbConnection.hgetall("hosts", function (err, obj) {
    console.dir(obj);
    });
}
};
```

EDIT:
tried another way. still failing.

```
module.exports = redisDb = (function() {
var config = require('../config');
var redis = require('redis'); 

return {
    connection: function(config) {
        var dbConnection = redis.createClient(config.db.port, config.db.host, {no_ready_check: true}); 

        dbConnection.auth(config.db.authKey, function() {
            console.log("Authenticated!");
        });
        return dbConnection
    },
    getValue: function(connection, callback) {
        connection.hgetall("hosts", function (err, obj) {
        console.dir(obj);
        });
    }
}
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the code work by simply declaring the connection in the parent function.

```
module.exports = _redisDb = (function() {

    var redis = require('redis'); 
    var config = require('../config');

    var dbConnection = redis.createClient(config.db.port, config.db.host, {no_ready_check: true});
    dbConnection.auth(config.db.authKey, function() {
        console.log("Authenticated!");
    });

    var getValue = function() {
            dbConnection.hgetall("hosts", function (err, obj) {
            console.dir(obj);
            });
        }

    return {
        getValue: getValue
    }
})();
```

While the above work,s I'd still like for someone to tell me how can I pass variables/objects between functions off the same module.

Answer (score 1):

Now one way is as you said to make `dbConnection` an object Property.
The other way is to call `init()` in `getValue()` which results in establishing different connection every time you want some value.

Because a DB Connection is a valuable resource, I'd say it's better to use the second variant.
Of course then you'll need to return `dbConnection` from `init()`.

PS: Global variables were made initially for such things and then people saw that fewer they are the better. That's why using global vars is considered a bad style.

Comment: but if i call dbconnection from init then every query will create a new connection. and generally, i'd want to reuse the same connection.

also, how do i make dbconnection an object property? can you please tell me?

Comment: one of the ways to do this is: { property_name: property_value_object }